# SharePoint workflow more than just an approve/reject process

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

How can you make the approval stage of a SharePoint workflow more than just an approve/reject process?

What I'm looking to achieve is the approver either rejects the request, or if the accept it, they need to enter further information. The example being a request for IT resources, if the approver accepts the request, then they need to provide details back to the requester related to resources.

Comment: With SharePoint Designer it might not be very straightforward, but since you are on SharePoint Online. I would suggest consider MS Flow, you can do lazy approval (comments/approval/reject within email) Have a look at this blog http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/07/02/two-stage-approval-process-using-ms-flow/